# Combination on bridge hand

Tags: combinations

In how many ways can a person get a bridge hand consisting of only aces and cards?
In how many ways can a person get a bridge hand which consists of cards 7 or lower?
Since i dont know bridge hand game nor play it, i dont know whats going on with the question.Please help me sir, our tutorial coming real close!

Comment: "aces and cards"? which cards?

Comment: In bridge a player is dealt thirteen cards. Aces are high, so cards 7 and below are 2s, 3s, 4s, 5s, 6s and 7s.

Comment: What do you mean by aces are high sir?

Comment: @Dave That aces are above seven in value (above all the other card values, in fact), not below. It differs from game to game (and some times even within a single game) whether aces are worth little or a lot. We call this either "aces are low" or "aces are high".